# How to pass images between two o more activities

Tags: android, arraylist, uri

I'm developing an app which consists in 4 activities. In the activity 2 and 3, the user have the possibility to take a picture. I pass the image taken in the activity 2 to activity 3 through intent, but my problem starts when the user take a picture in the activity 3, because I don't know how to pass the 2 images taken to activity 4, which save the pictures to server.

Passing image taken in activity 2

```
intent.putExtra("image", bitmap);
```

Receiving image in activity 3 from activity 2

```
Uri fileUri=getIntent().getData();
ArrayList<Uri> mBitmaps = new ArrayList<>(2);
mBitmaps.add(fileUri);
mBitmaps.add(fileUriDanos);
```

Passing the array of images to activity 4:

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("imagenes",mBitmaps);
```

Receiving the array in activity 4 (app crash here, only when one of the array items is null, not photo taken in one of previous activities)
`intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("imagenes");`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

ArrayList<Uri> images = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("imagenes");
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, since there isnt any logcat for crash displayed and by looking at your code I guess the reason why your app is crashing might be "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION". Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html) for more information

Intent has the capability of transferring 1MB Bundle.

Try saving the images in internal file system for every activity and just passing the file path in intent to the next activity and finally retrieving all the images in activity 4.

This will avoid the crashing of app as it worked out for me.

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer, u can mark this as an answer so others can get benefit out of it.